# Spring security and multiple log in forms

Tags: web-applications, spring-security

I have a web application using spring security in order to manage authentication.
My client has 2 login forms, my spring security config is as follows:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="always">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="permitAll" />

        <form-login login-processing-url="/user/login" login-page="/user/login/unauthorized" 
            default-target-url="/user/firstLogin" authentication-failure-url="/user/login/failure" />

        <form-login login-processing-url="/user/relogin" login-page="/user/login/unauthorized" 
            default-target-url="/user/reLoginFromClient" authentication-failure-url="/user/login/failure" />

        <logout logout-url="/user/logout/spring" logout-success-url="/user/logout/success" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    </http>
```

The first form-login element works fine i.e. i am able to login from the `/user/login` URL.
However, when i try to login from the second url `/user/relogin`, i get a 415:unsupported media type response from the server.

Note that if i switch the two  elements, the one that is on top works fine and the bottom one results in a 415 response.

I did as suggested in the selected answer, my configuration now looks like this:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="always" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="permitAll" />
        <custom-filter after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="reLoginFilter"/>
        <form-login login-processing-url="/user/login" login-page="/user/login/unauthorized" 
            default-target-url="/user/firstLogin" authentication-failure-url="/user/login/failure" />
        <logout logout-url="/user/logout/spring" logout-success-url="/user/logout/success" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>  
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="reLoginFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/user/relogin"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailHandler" />
    </beans:bean> 

    <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/user/relogin/success"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/user/login/failure"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are your reasons for using `auto-config="true"` and `create-session="always"` ?

Comment: @Luke, probably none. I need to first validate this before i remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple `<form-login>` elements within a single `<http>` element.

Instead you could use one and add a second by defining a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` bean and inserting it using the `custom-filter` element.

You should also probably remove the `auto-config`. Creating a session for every request is also rarely required, so I would remove the `create-session` attribute  too, unless you are sure you need it.

Comment: Thanks Luke, ill try the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.